# C# foreach Order By skipping some values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have dates in a `List<model>` & i am doing a `foreach` with date property. These dates are dates of a month.

```
foreach (var item in emps.OrderBy(m => m.a.Entry_Date).ToList())
{
.....
}
```

Now my requirement is that i have another `List<OT>` which contains some dates from the same month.

I want the `foreach` to iterate in such a way that dates in the `List<OT>` are iterated first & rest dates are iterated by Order By clause.

What is easy way out here?

Comment: `.ToList()` is *redundant* in the context: `foreach` will do on `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: use for each statements and do it

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It depends on the requirement. If you want to modify the emps collection inside foreach loop then you have to use ToList(). We cannot decide if it is redundant unless we see the whole code from the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the source collection into two parts, apply the order and then concat both together into one collection again:

```
List<DateTime> datelist = ...

var firstpart = emps.Where( m => datelist.Contains( m.a.Entry_Date ) ).ToList();
var secondpart = emps.Except( firstpart ).OrderBy( m => m.a.Entry_Date );
var collection = firstpart.Concat( secondpart );

foreach ( var item in collection )
{
    ....
}
```

[.Net Fiddle Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cmtEdL)